# Implementing reactivity in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, rxjs, vue-reactivity

I use vanilla JS for interactive webpages, and I'm trying to understand whether my design pattern is correctly implementing the principle of reactivity.

(Note: I'm not referring to the library React -- though I'm happy for answers to draw on features or strategies of such libraries).

My basic understanding is that you have some data which acts as your single source of truth, you listen for changes, and when that data changes, your page|app|component re-renders to reflect that.

Here's a simplified version of what I do, with questions after.

Let's say I have my single source of truth:

```
let data = {}
data.someContent = 'Hello World'
data.color = 'red'
```

and my app's markup in a template string for dynamic rendering:

```
function template(data) {
  return `
  <div id="app" style="color:${data.color}">${data.someContent}</div>
`
}
// assume there are also plain HTML inputs on the page, outside of what gets re-rendered.
```

a function that renders based on the data:

```
function render(data) {
  document.getElementById('app').innerHtml = template(data)
}
```

then, for the equivalent of reactivity from client-side updates:

```
document.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  data[e.target.id] = e.target.value // update data to reflect input
  render(data) // re-render based on new data
})
```

and from server-side updates:

```
function fetchDataAndReRender() {
  data.propToUpdate = // fetch data from server
  render(data) // again, re-render
return
}
```

So, we've got the single source of truth and re-rendering based on data updates.

- Is there another pillar to this, beyond the trio of data, listeners, and rendering?
- I understand that libraries usually listen directly to changes on the `data` object, e.g. via Proxies.  It seems like the only advantage to that is avoiding manually calling `render()`.  Is that correct?

--

EDIT: Adding a link to a blog post that mimics the vanilla reactive strategy above: https://css-tricks.com/reactive-uis-vanillajs-part-1-pure-functional-style/  There are some minor variations, but it serves as a good reference point for anyone interested in this style.

Comment: Could whoever left the close vote indicate why?  As far as I can tell, this is on topic for SO, shows work, isn't a duplicate, etc.

Comment: Maybe [this is something](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) that can help understand what reactivity is.

Comment: @Picci Thanks!  As far as I can tell, what I'm describing *is* reactive -- that's why I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  There are certainly other implementations of reactivity, but the result and principle seem the same.

Comment: I have a long comment that I have posted as an answer since it is too long to fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing I'm missing here is a way to optimize re-renders.

Interacting with the DOM is expensive, so apart from using a `Proxy` around your data/state to automatically call `render`, you would ideally want to avoid just replacing all the HTML for your app if only one element or, say, one attribute, has changed:

- Consider updating an `<input>`. If you are not able to detect that only its value has changed and update that, and instead you replace the whole HTML that includes this input, the cursor will move to the end after each re-render (so probably after every character I type).
- Consider a drag & drop feature. If you are not able to detect that the user is dragging something across the screen and only update the CSS `transform` property on it, and instead you replace the whole HTML that includes the element being dragged, the performance is going to be horrible. Also, you'll be interrupting the drag events, so this won't work at all.

Another possible optimization would be batching updates, so if you update your data 3 times in a row, you could potentially only update the HTML once with the final result. You already mentioned you debounce continuous input events, which would be one way of doing it.

Answers to your comments:

(1) I assumed you wanted a general purpose solution, that's where being able to detect changes and only update the parts of the DOM that need to be updated is a must.

If your only need to (re)render small static chunks of HTML, then you can probably go without this. The main two reasons being:

- As you said, there's no interactivity, so you'll not experience the issues I exemplified.
- As you updates are small, you are unlikely to see any performance issues by replacing blocks of HTML instead of trying to update the existing elements in the DOM.

(2) In any case, the main problem you would have to face if trying to update only what has change would not be finding the data that has changed (regardless of whether you use a Proxy or not), but to map that to the elements that need to be updated and actions that would perform those updates.

(3) You can also make compromises on the app side, say, that the data must be immutable (like with React).

Comment: (1) Re: updating an input -- probably not clear from my example, but usually my inputs are outside the element that would be re-rendered (i.e., it's not just a whole page wipe).  But point taken.  (2) For diffing in general, how about saving `previousData` and looping through `data` and only updating elements elements corresponding to change?  (3)  My reason for avoiding Proxy is the inability to easily detect changes in nested arrays and objects.  (PS: appreciate the response; just working through the ideas, here.)

Comment: I should add that I usually debounce continuous input events, and for one-time events, I'll wait for the event to finish (like `mouseup` to re-render).

Comment: @ultraGentle Just updated the answer to respond to that, but in short, according to the use case you describe, it looks like your solution could work as is. Most of the stuff I'm mentioning would only apply to a general-purpose solution.

Comment: Re: _"Interacting with the DOM is expensive"_ Please, when / if, you have time, can you cite an example? Many thanks. I often hear this as a non-React dev, but I have never (yet) found updating the DOM via JS (or DOM presentation via CSS) to be slow or problematic in any perceptible way. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine Depends a lot on use case and the devices you expect your app to run on. Back in the jQuery days I remember how keeping the references to the nodes you want to work with was considered a good practice, as obviously having to find them again each time took more time, which could be noticeable when implementing features such as data grids, long lists, formatted inputs or live previews.

Comment: For example, imagine you have a form and on every change on that form, you want to update a live preview that shows how that data will be displayed to an end user or whatever. Obviously, this can be made fast with plain JS, but if you take this approach of updating `innerHTML` on each key press, and the preview is complex/big enough, the input fields will soon start feeling sluggish. You can mitigate some of this by debouncing that update, but you can get further without this if you can update the individual nodes that need to be updated rather than using `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for that example, @Danziger. This helps to confirm - at least in part,- my long-held suspicion that direct DOM updates via JS (which is my go-to approach) tend not to be slow, though large-scale updates via `innerHTML`  may be. And that the problem _React_, _Preact_ etc. set out to solve is the latter, not the former. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: Exactly, all these frameworks end up dumping updates to the DOM eventually, yet it is generally accepted they tend to be faster than doing it with plain JS, which is a bit of a misconception. You could actually implement something just as fast or even faster with plain JS if you know what you are doing. But if you don't, you are better off using any of these frameworks, as they'll automatically apply some optimizations you wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: And that's generally great, but could also turn against you, as many devs jump straight into frameworks without understanding what's happening behind the scenes, so when they encounter a scenario where the framework was not able to optimize something or just reach the limit of what the framework can do automatically (meaning, without you putting a bit more thought into it) they are clueless.

Comment: Re: general solution (as clarification, not argument) so far the design pattern in my answer has worked generally in that I link all "reactive" elements to the data via an auto mapping of ids to properties, with classes to encapsulate larger groups, allowing for complete or partial updates when the data changes.  And indeed, sometimes an input element needs to be affected by changes, in which case the specific implementation of debouncing, selection, and cursor tracking matters for the UX.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question. It is a comment too long to fit in the comment space.

**What "thinking reactive" means, at least in my opinion**

"thinking reactive" means, as far as I can tell, that you model your problem in terms of "streams of events" and the "side effects" such events have, for instance what happens on your screen when some of these events occur.

In an front end app, the first event is "somebody opens the app" and the side effect is that "you see something on your screen", usually the browser.

Then, starting from that event, you switch to another stream of event, or probably the combination of many streams of events.

This combination can be the combination of:

- "the user clicks buttonA"
- "the user scrolls down the page"

Each of these streams of events has its own side effects:

- "the user clicks buttonA" may lead you to another page
- "the user scrolls down the page" may trigger a call to a remote service for the next page of data

The summary is that, in reactive style, your write the book of "what happens when" and then you unfold this book.

In more precise terms, you can **declare** how an entire application will behave as a single stream of events and the related side effects.

Once your declaration is complete (and correct) you simply subscribe to the stream and let the events, and their side effect, flow.

Is it worth programming this way down to the extreme? Probably not, as all extreme positions.

Is it convenient some times? Definitely yes.